# Xcode: How do I wrap a long string around to the next line in the xcode editor

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

I've got a long string an sql statement, which I want to wrap onto the next line in the xcode editor, how do I wrap it round e.g.

```
[db executeUpdate:@"insert into test (rid, one, two, amount, startdate, recurrance) values (nil, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
[db executeUpdate:@"insert into test (rid, one, two, amount, values"  
                   " startdate, recurrance)(nil, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue... call me paranoid.. but i like my sqlstring to look pretty and easy to trace in case something went wrong i used the stringWithFormat

example:

```
NSString sqlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@",
                   @"SELECT name, address, phone",
                   @"FROM whateverDatabase",
                   @"LEFT JOIN ...",
                   @"WHERE ...",
                   @"AND ...."];
```

hopefully if this is what you are looking for
(i figured i posted on the wrong page... maybe here is better)