# Xcode: How can I add large sql querys to the xcode editor without double quotes at the start and end of each line?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I asked a question earlier today "Xcode: How do I wrap a long string around to the next line in the xcode editor" ...

[Xcode: How do I wrap a long string around to the next line in the xcode editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778589/xcode-how-do-i-wrap-a-long-string-around-to-the-next-line-in-the-xcode-editor)

... but this is going to be inconvenient, I`ve got some quite large sql statements, which are nicely formatted. In PHP I now you can do something like >> sql then << something like that.

Is there something similar in xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You'll have to escape the double quotes, or quote using single quotes instead.

Comment: I know what you mean by escape them \" but I'm not sure what you mean, or how that would look

Comment: Put a blackslash before the quote: `NSString *sql = @"INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (\"my string\");"`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue... call me paranoid.. but i like my sqlstring to look pretty and easy to trace in case something went wrong
i used the stringWithFormat

example:

```
NSString sqlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@",
                   @"SELECT name, address, phone",
                   @"FROM whateverDatabase",
                   @"LEFT JOIN ...",
                   @"WHERE ...",
                   @"AND ...."];
```

hopefully if this is what you are looking for